# How to fix '\n' from json?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I'm trying to fix an json file created with a function called

`create`. But I keep getting this format:

**CURRENT INPUT**

```
"[\n    [\n        1,\n        1111,\n        \"2019-07-17\",\n        \"11:00:00\",\n        \"12:00:00\",\n        505\n    ],\n    [\n        2,\n        2233,\n        \"2019-05-03\",\n        \"16:00:00\",\n        \"17:30:00\",\n        205\n    ],\n    [\n        3,\n        2245,\n        \"2019-05-04\",\n        \"17:30:00\",\n        \"19:00:00\",\n        204\n    ],\n    [\n        4,\n        1354,\n        \"2019-05-05\",\n        \"8:00:00\",\n        \"9:30:00\",\n        206\n    ]\n]"
```

**I tried the following code:**

```py
def create(data):
    """creates an outputfile"""
    data_filename="iss_tui_records.js"
    with open(data_filename, "w", encoding="utf-8") as file_handle:
        json.dump(data, file_handle)

data=fetchall() #from mysql-connector-python
for e in data:
  data_json=(json.dumps(data, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '), default=str))
  print("export",datos_json)
  create(data_json)
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
"[
  [1,1111,2019-07-17,11:00:00,12:00:00,505],
  [2,2233,2019-05-03,16:00:00,17:30:00",205],
  (...)
]"
```

Comment: What do you want instead?

Comment: `data_filename ` shoud be `.json` I think also what is `data`?

Comment: You're dumping the data object to Json twice. This means the second time it's is dumping a string to json which is inserting all sorts of escape characters and such

Comment: @ScottHunter fix it as a normal json file.

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh no, I already test it both, is not necessary

Comment: @Alex can you show me how to do it? I'm new in this process. Thank you

Comment: get rid of the `data_json=(json.dumps(data, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '), default=str))` line

Comment: @GUNTERSAMA It would be helpful if you included the raw input and expected output in the question.

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh I need it, otherwise I can use the date from the mysql data

Comment: @Alex Ok it's done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `data` object is a simple dict or list,all you need to do is:

```
with open(output_path, 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
```

This will correctly dump to the output file.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bsentor.py", line 248, in <module>
    json.dump(data, sort_keys=True, indent=4, default=str)
TypeError: dump() missing 1 required positional argument: 'fp'

Comment: You missed the `f` argument in the call to `json.dump`

Comment: @GUNTERSAMA I would suggest you consult [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to writing a good question for future posts. Following those guidelines will make people less likely to downvote your question.